# jquery not firing at all

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Starting a new site and can't get any jquery to fire. I've tried just executing some in the console in browser to test, moved from external jquery to inside the `<head>` and can't get anything. It isn't even seeing that first function as existing. I've a feeling it's something so stupidly simple I'm overlooking, but I'm just exhausted from looking over the same <100 lines. One of the errors I try when manually getting the width is this.

`Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '[object Window]' is not a valid selector."`

Suggestions?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <script href="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script href="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <title>Daniel Jenkins</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Libre+Baskerville:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script>
        function set_container_sizes(){
            console.log("Setting div sizes");
            var window_width = $(window).width();
            console.log("Window is "+window_width+"px wide");
            var window_height = $(window).height();
            console.log("Window is "+window_height+"px tall");
            $('#outer_container').css('max-height',window_height+'px');
            $('#outer_container').css('max-width',window_width+'px');
        }

        $( document ).ready(function(){
            console.log("Document now ready");
            set_container_sizes();
        });

        $( window ).resize(function(){
            console.log("Window resized");
            set_container_sizes();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="outer_container">
        <div id="inner_top">
            <div id="top_head">
                Daniel L. Jenkins
            </div>
        </div>Hello there       <div id="inner_bottom">

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use `src` instead of `href` when importing javascript files. Btw, your code works well: http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/TM35N/

Comment: Thank you and thank you. I am planning a few interesting things. This is literally as far as I am at the moment though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is that you are using "href" inside the script tag instead of "src".

Comment: I have no idea where I got that href from, but I feel like orbital bombardment at the moment. Thank you for that

Answer (score 4):

I think it should be `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>`